# Copying Large files - does it create an empty file in the destination?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a filewatcher script which notifies when a file is missing or it is empty. The files that I'm expecting - some of them are big. The files are copied by another script/job from a different path (for which I don't have access). Once in a while, I get a false alert saying that the file was received empty [I'm using an `else` condition in `if [ -s $file ]` command], but upon checking, the file is not empty. Only logical explanation that I can come up for this is while copying large files, may be unix creates an empty file first? By some weird coincidence, my script is checking the file at 'that' time? My script runs every ten minutes in the background.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: I've tackled this by adding a 30 seconds `sleep` into the code for now. Hope it works. But I still don't know why an empty file is copied at first! :/

Comment: This could depend on what utility is being used for doing the actual copy.

Comment: Various sources, so hard to know how the file is being copied. So far the 30 seconds of sleep helps :-D

Answer (score 1):

If the files are being copied then there will be a very short moment when the file has been opened for writing but before any file content has been flushed to disk.

One way of copying files to avoid such a race condition is to copy them to the destination directory with a temporary suffix and then rename in place once the copy is completed:

```
cp "$source" "$target.tmp" &&
    mv "$target.tmp" "$target"
```

Your receiving code would be written to ignore these temporary files.

Comment: If the files are being transferred by e.g. `rsync`, then they are first written to temporary files that are later renamed to the correct destination filenames, in a way logically similar to what you show. This is why I asked what utility they used for copying (back in [February 2018](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397081/copying-large-files-does-it-create-an-empty-file-in-the-destination#comment757871_397081)).

Comment: @Kusalananda indeed it's possible. We don't know. But what is true is that regardless of what temporary filename pattern is used to copy the files to the destination, that pattern should be ignored for files "in transit"